# Deleting a voiding journal in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite

Need help on deleting a voiding journal in NetSuite. I can't delete, as it is tied to another transaction, but I also can't release the journal from the bill payment.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite tells me it is not possible to delete a voiding journal.  The issues you need to clear up are (a) the bills or expense reports paid on that check now show as open and ready to be paid, and (b) the bill payment and voiding journal net to zero leaving nothing to mark reconciled in the bank reconciliation.

The workaround I use to "un-voided" a bill payment is a two step process.  It's not as clean and easy as I would like but it works.

(1) Create an account with type "Bank" and name it something like "Cash Pass Through".  It will be used for adjustments like this and should always have a zero balance.

(2) Post a manual journal entry.  Credit cash to reverse the cash impact of the voiding journal.  Debit your "Cash Pass Through" account.  It will be cleared out in the next step.  Set the memo to something like "Bill Payment # XXXXX:  Reversal of Voiding Journal".

(3) Find the vendor bills or expense reports that the original check paid, and pay them again, using your "Cash Pass Through" account created in the first step.  Make sure the bill payment is not set to be printed.  This is an adjusting entry only.  No check should be created.

The end result is:

- Your bills or expense reports that has an open/ready to pay status after the void now have a "Paid in Full" status.
- The "Cash Pass Through" account has a net balance of zero.
- The bank reconciliation will show the voiding journal entry and the manual adjustment you created, which net out to zero.  Both can be marked as reconciled.  Later when the original original bill payment clears you can mark it as reconciled.

I would prefer something like an "un-void" button in NetSuite but unfortunately that isn't possible.  Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: You might be able to create a custom workflow that imbeds a custom "Reverse" button on the void transaction.  That custom button could be linked to actions that automates the steps I outlined above.